# Program invoked with subprocess.Popen() does not recognize two arguments passed as one

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this function in python script on WSL2 and I run it as a super user:

```
import subprocess

def flash() -> None:

    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ["JLinkExe", ""],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True,
        text=True
    )

    # Read the response from JLinkExe
    response = p.stdout.read()
    print(response)
```

As you can see I try to run program `JLinkExe` which is a command line utility with it's own shell `J-Link>`. For some reason my `print()` function prints this:

```
SEGGER J-Link Commander V7.60 (Compiled Dec 14 2021 11:40:17)
DLL version V7.60, compiled Dec 14 2021 11:40:00

Unknown command line option .
```

First two lines indicate that `application JLinkExe` did run, but for some reason there is a `.` appended at the back of the arguments or empty argument is not recognized which is weird.

---

If I change this line:

```
["JLinkExe", "-nogui 1"]
```

The response also changes:

```
SEGGER J-Link Commander V7.60 (Compiled Dec 14 2021 11:40:17)
DLL version V7.60, compiled Dec 14 2021 11:40:00

Unknown command line option -nogui 1.
```

Again `.` is appended to the back of the arguments...

---

If I run the same command as a super user directly in WSL everything looks fine:

```
$ sudo JLinkExe -nogui 1
SEGGER J-Link Commander V7.60 (Compiled Dec 14 2021 11:40:17)
DLL version V7.60, compiled Dec 14 2021 11:40:00

Connecting to J-Link via USB...O.K.
Firmware: J-Link STLink V21 compiled Aug 12 2019 10:29:20
Hardware version: V1.00
S/N: 775087052
VTref=3.300V

Type "connect" to establish a target connection, '?' for help
J-Link>
```

Why are my arguments not recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.` appended to the arguments, that's the output of the `JLinkExe` command which is an English sentence which ends with a `.`:

```
Unknown command line option <argument>.
```

Neither `""` nor `"-nogui 1"` are valid arguments for `JLinkExe`, but `"-nogui"` is, which expects another one, `"1"`.

You need two separate arguments:

```
["JLinkExe", "-nogui", "1"]
```

If you want to invoke just `JLinkExe` with no arguments, don't pass an empty string as an argument:

```
["JLinkExe"]
```